# how to get return URL in pay pal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have create a business account in paypal and I got all key and I am not aware of creating return URL could any one please let me know how to create a return url with the complete details?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the returnURL="www.xxxxxxx.com" in the request of your payment, however you can also simply put it in the paypal account for a paypal standard payment/button:

**PayPal account solution:**
Log in and click the Profile subtab under My Account. Click the Website Payment Preferences link under Selling Preferences. Click the On radio button to enable Auto Return. Enter the Return URL.

NVP Parameter (**PayPal Express Checkout** -SetExpressCheckout)

```
METHOD(Must be set to SetExpressCheckout)
TOKEN =
*RETURNURL*=
CANCELURL
REQCONFIRMSHIPPING
NOSHIPPING
ALLOWNOTE
LOCALECODE
PAYMENTDETAILS
```